# render every even ListItem backgroundColor grey and every odd one's white in React-Native

Tags: react-native, listitem

For my react-native application I'm using `ListItem`. I think there should be some way that I can be able to render my `ListItems`' `backgroundColor` automated one after another, just like in picture.

[image]

and Here is my `List` code right now.

```
<List>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Body>
                           <Text style={{fontSize: 10, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Lead Info Update: Updated lead info bar . 2017-11-15 14:27:02</Text>
                           <Text style={{fontSize: 15}} note><Icon style={{fontSize: 15}} name="calendar"/> 2017-11-15 14:28:44</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Body>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 10, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Lead Info Update: Updated lead info bar . 2017-11-15 14:27:02</Text>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}} note><Icon style={{fontSize: 15}} name="calendar"/> 2017-11-15 14:28:44</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </ListItem>
</List>
```

Do you know how to figure out this?

Answer (score 4):

Well I am not sure what List from native-base behind the scene is using, if it is Flatlist than you can simply replace List from native-base with Flatlist from react-native like below

```
<FlatList
renderItem={(item, index)=>{
//add check on the basis of isEven = (index%2 ===0);
<ListItem>
     <Body>
       <Text style={{fontSize: 10, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Lead Info Update: Updated lead info bar . 2017-11-15 14:27:02</Text>
       <Text style={{fontSize: 15}} note><Icon style={{fontSize: 15}} name="calendar"/> 2017-11-15 14:28:44</Text>
     </Body>
</ListItem>}
}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using an `if` **inline** like other languages like php, javascript, etc. And using `%2` we can know the pairs and odd. `index` is the current position of your iterated item.

**React Native**:

```
(index % 2)?
    <ListItem style={ backgroundColor: '#ccc' }>
        <Body>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 10, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Lead Info Update: Updated lead info bar . 2017-11-15 14:27:02</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}} note><Icon style={{fontSize: 15}} name="calendar"/> 2017-11-15 14:28:44</Text>
        </Body>
    </ListItem>
:
    <ListItem style={ backgroundColor: '#fff' }>
        <Body>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 10, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Lead Info Update: Updated lead info bar . 2017-11-15 14:27:02</Text>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}} note><Icon style={{fontSize: 15}} name="calendar"/> 2017-11-15 14:28:44</Text>
        </Body>
    </ListItem>
```

This works for me, I hope it is helpful for you.

Regards!

Comment: Using React-Native-Element’s ListItem you can do it in following way:
```<FlatList
   data={this.state.data}                      
   renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
   <ListItem
     containerStyle = {{ backgroundColor: index % 2 == 0  ? "#f2f2f2" : "#FFFFFF" }}
   />)}
/>```